# passing instance variable as parameter in method within same class?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

Is it possible to pass an instance variable as a parameter to a method within the same class?

please see below code:

```
public class Example 
{

   private int var1;  //instance variable to be changed


   public Example()
   {
       var1 = 0;
   }

   public void changeVar()
   {
       this.changeVar1(var1);  //call method to change from within class
   }

   private void changeVariable(int variable)  //changes passed instance variable
   {
       variable = 2;
   }

}
```

Used in this example, it seems silly because you could easily change var1 through the first method call, changeVar(), but I have a more complex program where I have multiple instance variables (var1, var2, var3, var4... var10).  I am trying to write changeVariable() once and pass each instance variable depending on what needs to be changed, as opposed to writing a separate method for each instance variable that needs to be changed, i.e. changeVariable1, changeVariable2... changeVariable10.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just silly - it won't work. Arguments in Java are *always* passed by value. So your `changeVariable` method is really just a no-op... it changes the value of the *parameter*, but that makes no difference to `var1`.

Without a more concrete example it's hard to know whether this is a good idea at all - I suspect it's not - but the way you're attempting it *definitely* won't work.

Comment: (ashamed.. I am still fairly new to java!)  I am attempting to make linked lists, where each variable is a reference to the first item in each list.  I basically have 10 lists.  I can't provide solid code to show just yet, as I am still only in planning stage.

Comment: @jcaoile: Do you really *need* 10 separate list variables? For one class to contain 10 list variables sounds like it's probably not a great design. A collection of lists, perhaps? It's hard to give more advice without knowing the concrete details.

Comment: Essentially, I have the separate lists to sort/group data based on a specific attribute, which is defined in the associated entity class (which make up the "links" for each of my linked lists).  You are correct in that the lists are defined in a class that is basically a collection class.  After further research from your answer and Dave's below, I am beginning to think that the most direct and simplest approach would be to have a method change each instance variable, or in this case, reference to the next link for each individual list.  Would you agree in this being a wise approach?

Comment: @jcaoile: It's still not really clear, but it sounds like you have several lists, all the same length. It would better to have *one* list of the entity type instead. But I may have misunderstood. A full example would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Java works; you can change a *property* of an object referenced by a parameter, but not the value of the parameter itself. You may want to consider a different approach if this is your need, perhaps a map that can be referenced by name.

(Technically you could pass the name of the property as a string and use reflection, but please don't.)